# Rearranging Elements For Array of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to rearrange elements in an array of arrays but have been unsucessful. Can anyone offer suggestions? Here are two options I have tried. I want to swap/switch places for the first and second elements.

arr1 is an array of arrays (i.e. arr[][]) so I created arr2 to be an updated arr1

```
var arr2 = [];

for (var n = 0; n <arr1.length; n++){
  arr2[n][0] = arr1[n][1];
  arr2[n][1] = arr1[n][0];
```

}

The other thing I tried was:

```
function order(arr[]){
  return [arr[n][1],arr[n][0], arr[n][2], arr[n][3]];
}

var arr2 = order(arr1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to create a new array for each item:

```
var arr2 = [];
for(var n = 0; n < arr1.length; n++) {
  arr2[n] = [arr1[n][1], arr1[n][0]];
}
```

Comment: Does this work if there are more than two elements for arr1[n]? i.e. there is an arr1[n][2] and arr1[n][3]

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939 This approach will work, but you would have to modify the code a bit. This code is for arrays with fixed size 2.

Comment: How can you modify this with more than two elements? just listing all the elements?

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939 Depends on what order you want, and how many elements you need.

Answer (score 1):

The first example you need to use a temporary variable for the switch:

```
var arr2 = [];

for (var n = 0; n <arr1.length; n++){
  var tempVal = arr1[n][1];
  arr2[n][1] = arr1[n][0];
  arr2[n][0] = tempArr;
}
```

The second example, in JS the variable shouldn't have brackets next to it, as it's just a loosely typed variable name.

```
function order(arr){
  return [arr[n][1],arr[n][0], arr[n][2], arr[n][3], arr[n][4]];
}

var arr2 = order(arr1);
```

Next time, before asking you should check the console. The [stackoverflow wiki page on JS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) has lots of great resources for learning to debug JS.

Comment: there is no need to use a temporary variable, arr1 isn't overridden

Comment: That's what every other answer does. If you have a better way, you should probably share.

Comment: James, he is saying "arr1 isn't overriden". There might be other solutions, but this statement is false.

Answer (score 1):

it's quite easy:

```
var a = arr1[n][0];
arr2[n][0] = arr1[n][1];
arr2[n][1] = a;
```

you need to save the first value as a variable, because if you do as you did(arr2[n][0] = arr1[n][1];), your two array indexes will have the same value.

You did:

```
a = 1, b = 2;
a = b;
b = a;
```

Which resolves in a = 2, b = 2

Also, your code as it is now, doesn't work. You need to create a new array for the simulation of multidimensional arrays in javascript.

```
for(i = 0; i < (yourdesiredamountofarrays); i++)
{
    yourarray[i] = new Array();
}
```

Comment: there is no need to use a temporary variable, arr1 isn't overridden

Comment: Sorry, I think you are mistaking. If he assigns arr[1] to arr[0] and then arr[0] to arr[1], then arr[1] will be the same as arr[0].